# Unsupported Media Type in Web API 2 during update (PUT) call

Tags: xml, asp.net-web-api

I am migrating an older application in Web API 1 to Web API2 in VS 2022. I am having a problem with the update methods.

I have a RESTful server with controllers for each table in a database. I am using the entity framework so each record in the database is represented by an Entity. My client-side program will populate the an entity with updated information, then sends it off the the server for database updating. Here is the relevant method in the client that sends this off to the server:

```
  Public Function UpdateCultivar(ByVal _entity As CultivarEntity) As Boolean
        Try
            url = "Cultivar/Update"
            ms = New MemoryStream()
            _serializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(CultivarEntity))
            _serializer.Serialize(ms, _entity)
            ms.Position = 0
            streamContent = New StreamContent(ms)
            responseTask = client.PutAsync(url, streamContent)
            responseTask.Wait()
            responseMessage = responseTask.Result
            If responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode = True Then
                Return deserializeBooleanResponse(responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync.Result)
            Else
                ProcessClientError(responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync.Result)
                Return Nothing
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            ProcessClientException(ex)
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
```

I take the updated entity serialize it to xml then do an async put.  (in another part of the code I set the client headers to "application/xml")

The relevant code on the server is:

```
       [Route("Update")]
        [HttpPut]
        [AcceptVerbs("PUT")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Put( [FromBody]  CultivarEntity _Entity)
        {
            Boolean result;
              try
            {
                _Entity = new CultivarEntity();
                _serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(_Entity.GetType());
                ioStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                ioStream = Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
                ioStream.Position = 0;
                _Entity = (CultivarEntity)_serializer.Deserialize(ioStream);
                result = _Accessor.UpdateCultivar(_Entity.cultivar_pk, _Entity);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e.Message);
            }
        }
```

I've tried numerous variations, but I always get the 415 Unsupported Media Type. The response from the server is:

```
RequestMessage = {Method: PUT, RequestUri: 'http://192.168.1.45/OrchardServices/api/Cultivar/Update', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Accept: application/xml
  ContentType: application/xml
  Content-Length: 293
}}
```

These routines worked fine in the old version of the application (minus the routing enhancements). What am I missing???

Thanks.

I've tried sending it with a content type of "application/octet-stream" with the same result.  I've tried removing all the API 2 attributes and reverting to the original "PUT("Update")"  Same result.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

As others have noted it was an issue of ContentType not being passed to the server. My strategy was to initialize a HttpClient when the sending class was initialized and I defined the content type as "application/xml" as seen below:

```
    Public Sub New()
    client = New HttpClient()
    client.BaseAddress = New Uri(urlBase)
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear()
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear()

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(New MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"))
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/xml")
```

This had worked fine in the previous version (WebApi 1 used with VS2010). What some other individuals noted was that the contentType had to be associated with the actual content, not the client object. When I finally realized this, the solution was simple, as seen in this snippet:

```
   Public Function UpdateCultivar(ByVal _entity As CultivarEntity) As Boolean
    Try
        url = "Cultivar/Update"
        ms = New MemoryStream()
        _serializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(CultivarEntity))
        _serializer.Serialize(ms, _entity)
        ms.Position = 0
        streamContent = New StreamContent(ms)
        streamContent.Headers.ContentType = New MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml") 'SOLVED PROBLEM!!
        responseTask = client.PutAsync(url, streamContent)
        responseTask.Wait()
```

I had to add this line of code to the /create route as well, because the xml entity was being passed to that as well.

Hope this helps others.